# Why does the terminal says "pop from empty list" in my RPN calculator project

Tags: python, tkinter, stack

Thats the code (srry it's kinda long) :

```
import tkinter as tk

# Définit une fonction pour évaluer une expression RPN
def evaluate(expression):
    pile = []
    for token in expression.split():
        if token.isdigit():
            pile.append(int(token))
        else:
            arg2 = pile.pop()
            arg1 = pile.pop()
            if token == "+":
                pile.append(arg1 + arg2)
            elif token == "-":
                pile.append(arg1 - arg2)
            elif token == "*":
                pile.append(arg1 * arg2)
            elif token == "/":
                pile.append(arg1 / arg2)
    return pile[0]


# Définit une fonction pour afficher les résultats sur l'écran de la calculatrice
def update_display(text):
    display.delete(0, tk.END)
    display.insert(0, text)

# Créer l'interface utilisateur
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculatrice NPI")
root.iconbitmap("Logo_cal.ico")
root.geometry("300x440")
root.minsize(300, 440)

# Ajouter un écran pour l'affichage des résultats
display = tk.Entry(root, width=40, borderwidth=5)
display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

# Ajouter des boutons pour les chiffres
button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "1"))
button_2 = tk.Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "2"))
button_3 = tk.Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "3"))
button_4 = tk.Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "4"))
button_5 = tk.Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "5"))
button_6 = tk.Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "6"))
button_7 = tk.Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "7"))
button_8 = tk.Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "8"))
button_9 = tk.Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "9"))
button_0 = tk.Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "0"))

# Ajouter des boutons pour les opérateurs
button_plus = tk.Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "+"))
button_soustraire = tk.Button(root, text="-", padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "-"))
button_multiplier = tk.Button(root, text="*", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "*"))
button_diviser = tk.Button(root, text="/", padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: display.insert(tk.END, "/"))

# Ajouter un bouton pour effacer un caractère
button_clear = tk.Button(root, text="Effacer", padx=80, pady=20, command=lambda: display.delete(len(display.get())-1))

# Ajouter un bouton pour évaluer l'expression RPN
button_equals = tk.Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=lambda: update_display(evaluate(display.get())))

# Positionner les boutons sur l'interface utilisateur
button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)

button_plus.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_soustraire.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_multiplier.grid(row=6, column=1)
button_diviser.grid(row=6, column=2)

button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_equals.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)

# Lancer l'interface utilisateur
root.mainloop()
```

Terminal gets this error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\33684\Desktop\Projet NSI Cal N P I\APPTEST.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    button_equals = tk.Button(root, text="=", padx=91, pady=20, command=lambda: update_display(evaluate(display.get())))
  File "c:\Users\33684\Desktop\Projet NSI Cal N P I\APPTEST.py", line 10, in evaluate
    arg2 = pile.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Problem is when I try to do an operation I don't get any result just that error I had a few other problems in the code that I fixed but still don't get the solution for that one, if somebody generous enough to help I'll take it.

Comment: Have you employed a debugger to step through your program? Evidently, the pile is empty at some point whilst there are still tokens left.

Comment: Yep did it but nothing came out of it.

Comment: Is the pile what you expected? Are the tokens what you expected? When and why is the pile empty while there are still tokens left?

Comment: When you cannot understand what happens in your code, that means that it is time to use a debugger if you have one, or add trace print in your code. I would bet a coin that in the `evaluate` function, `expression` or `token` are not what you expect.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, would 2+2 first get 2 appended to pile, and then see the + and try to pop 2 items off the pile? Or are you using suffix notation?

Comment: Yeah, I'm co-coding this with another developer and I don't get all of it so I'm hoping someone understands what's wrong better than I haha, also tried to use a debugger but It wasn't really helping.

Comment: The `evaluate()` function is for an RPN calculator (it says so in the comment). So you need to do `1 2 +` not `1 + 2`. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: Actually as I'm using Tkinter and how the graphics are coded I can't really do that maybe that's where the error coming from, gonna check that, thanks

Comment: What is the expression causing the error?

Comment: If the expression is something like `"1+2"`, then `expression.split()` will return `["1+2"]`, not `["1", "+", "2"]`.

Answer (score 0):

after testing code locally, the issue is that you provide, let's say, "1+2" as the only argument. Then you use `expression.split()` but there is no space between 1 and +. Thus expresion is `'1+2'`
This means token in the for loop will be '1+2', not "1".

One way to fix this is when inserting add a space on numbers and operators:

```
display.insert(tk.END, "1 "))
```

but in this case, if you were providing "1 + 2" it would still fail.

This is the portion of your code:

```
for token in expression.split():
    if token.isdigit():
        pile.append(int(token))
    else:
        arg2 = pile.pop()
        arg1 = pile.pop()
```

So first token is 1.
Is it digit? Yes. pile = ["1"]

Second token is +.
Is it digit? No.
Then:
arg2 = pile.pop() = 1
arg1 = pile.pop() = ?? Error. Pile is already empty.

It can be quickly adapted:

```
for token in expression.split():
    if token.isdigit():
        pile.append(int(token))
    else:
        expresion = token

if expresion == "+":
    return pile[0] + pile[1]
elif expresion == "-":
    return pile[0] - pile[1]
elif expresion == "*":
    return pile[0] * pile[1]
elif expresion == "/":
    return pile[0] / pile[1]
else: return "unknown expresion"
```

Still the code can be much improved. What happens if I enter "1 + 2 - 3", the code will operate: 1 - 2. So that's something to take into account.

Comment: But the error is on `arg2 = pile.pop()` (the first `pop()`, not the second one), so your explanation does not apply.

Comment: @acw1668 you are right, after running the code, original failure is because the expression entered had no spaces, and as such expression.split() was returning one single token.

Comment: Adding space after digit will not let user to input something like "12 + 34".

Comment: True, but there are many things the current code can't do, like 1 + 2 - 3. I would definetly do `for charcater in expresion` which will allow for a better processing of the input.